# ImportError: cannot import name 'request' from 'flask' when serving flask app via apache2 and wsgi on VM

Tags: python, apache, flask, wsgi

So i deployed my flask app to my linux debian VM and served it via wsgi and apache2 (lynx serverIpAdress/mailService).

My Problem:

When i run the app using the command `python mailService.py` it runs fine but when i try to access it via apache2 i get the following error:

```
[wsgi:error] [pid 8771:tid 139918835648256] [client 192.168.1.50:37344]   File "/var/www/Bulma/MailService/mailService.wsgi", line 5, in <module>
[wsgi:error] [pid 8771:tid 139918835648256] [client 192.168.1.50:37344]     from mailService import app as application
[[wsgi:error] [client 192.168.1.50:37344]   File "/var/www/Bulma/MailService/mailService.py", line 2, in <module>
[Thu Jan 09 08:45:42.595785 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 8771:tid 139918835648256] [client 192.168.1.50:37344]     from flask import request, jsonify,json
[Thu Jan 09 08:45:42.595839 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 8771:tid 139918835648256] [client 192.168.1.50:37344] ImportError: cannot import name 'request' from 'flask' (unknown location)
[Thu Jan 09 08:53:41.179747 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 8771:tid 139918877611776] [client 192.168.1.50:37366] mod_wsgi (pid=8771): Failed to exec Python script file '/var/www/Bulma/Mai$
```

my mailService.py:

```
import flask
from flask import request,json
import smtplib

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

@app.route('/api/v1/resources/mailFactory',methods=['POST'])
def mailFactory():

    Json = request.get_json()
    Application = Json['Application']
    context = int(Application)
    switcher = {
        0: themisMailService
    }
    if Application:
        func = switcher.get(context)
        return func(Json)


def themisMailService(Json):
    sender_email = "test@gmail.com"
    receiver_email = "test@gmail.com"
    message = """From: From Person <from@fromdomain.com>
        To: To Person <to@todomain.com>
        Subject: SMTP e-mail test

        This is a test e-mail message.
        """

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()

    # Login Credentials for sending the mail
    server.login(sender_email, "gjwvttjphdrhivoo") #app password inserted

    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
    server.quit()       
    print ("Successfully sent email")


#app.run(host= '0.0.0.0')
```

Additional Information:

1. I have set up a flask-env in my working directory not sure if it is necessary though.
2. I have already tried launching command pip install flask, pip install request.
3. PIP version is pip 18.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)
4. Flask version is Flask 1.1.1
5. App.run() has been commented by my app as it has been to my understanding that is no longer needed as wsgi is already serving the app.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to receive passed by your server, you can simply do thing like that:

```py
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    if request.method == 'GET':
         return 'It is HTTP get!'
```

You don't have to import 'request'. There is also requests package, but i think that it's not your intention to use it (it's for making requests by python) :)

Comment: Hello Dawid,
Actually my Service was already in place i just didn't find it necessary to add it in my post as it was definitely not related to the problem. Right now it is an import problem. Maybe there is no need to import dependencies like request or Json i don't know i'm completely new to flask, but definitely we need to import flask so as to define the application.

Comment: What I say is, that you don't need to import 'request', it's build in flask app - sorry for me being not precise.
Of course you need to import flask.

Comment: Yeah dawid you're right indeed i don't need to specify all these imports only the flask one :D.

Comment: answer might be relevant but not linked to the title of the post

Comment: So you down-voted because title does not correspond to what you've been looking for? Maybe adjust title instead?